# Tensorflow Node-js, TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I am trying to load a local tensorflowjs model on my Node server but am getting the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported.
```

This is how  I  am importing the Tensorflowjs packages:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
```

and loading the model like this:

```
const ssd_model_path =
    'file://models/ssd_model/model.json'

this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(ssd_model_path);
```

My dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.5.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^1.2.11",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.2.3",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "jimp": "^0.9.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think `tfjs-node` is for NodeJS, and `tfjs` is for the web browser. You shouldn't use both at the same time, because `tfjs-node` has every thing as dependencies for NodeJS.

If you look at a NodeJS example, then you'll see doesn't use `tfjs`

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mnist-node

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this exactly answers your question, but it might be slightly related. For us the [issue](https://github.com/epfml/disco/issues/446), was that we had a library, say **LIB**, which invoked `tf.loadLayersModel`. We were using **LIB** in the **BROWSER** (browser code) and **SERVER** (back-end server).  We basically wanted to use both tfjs and tfjs-node at the "same time", meaning we wanted to make a common library for both front and back end that used tfjs.

> Note that we were only calling the `tf.loadLayersModel` code in **LIB** only through the browser.

To make the **LIB** --- more specifically tfjs --- compatible with the **BROWSER** and the **SERVER**, we [solved](https://github.com/epfml/disco/pull/456) it by adding the following conditional import:

```js
// Only use tfjs-node env in node env
// Note, due to webpack? checks we
// put the string outside of the import
// to take advantage of lazy loading.
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const tfjsNode = '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'
    await import(tfjsNode)
}
```

This allowed us to in the **LIB** have the load layers code

```js
this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://modelsPath/model.json');
```

And then call it in the **SERVER** to load from the file system.